# How do I configure ADB for the Samsung Galaxy Y?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-y

How do I configure ADB to recognize my Samsung Galaxy Y? I have installed the USB driver. but when I run `adb devices` it does not list anything. Following are the steps I followed.

1. Declare your application as "debuggable" in your Android Manifest.
2. Turned on "USB Debugging" on your device from Setting->applications-> development
3. I have my Google USB Driver installed.

   I use windows 7 so to install driver I did these
4. Connected my Galaxy Y computer's USB port
5. Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage
6. Select Devices in the left pane.
7. Locate and expand Other device in the right pane. Now I just don't see my device listed there
   I am new to the forum and cannot post images so here's the link for the screen shot what device manager looks like

http://www24.zippyshare.com/v/66454912/file.html

Comment: Please note that development questions are generally off-topic here. However, since setting up ADB is a fairly common power-user task, that portion of your question (which is the core of it) is fine. I've reworded this to focus on that aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your USB Debugging mode enabled? Go to `Settings->Applications->Development`, and check the "USB Debugging" mode. This will help the ADB detect your device.

You may refer to the [Android Developer Documentation: Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) for further information and details.

Comment: I already followed the document before posting and edited my post to mention what steps I followed.

Comment: @Abhilasha Are you able to see your phone as a "Mass Storage Device" on your computer?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see it.

Comment: Have you installed Samsung Kies? Try if anything from this post works: [Android app in debug mode on Samsung Galaxy Y S5360](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8804473/713354)

Comment: Thanks a ton! It worked like magic...I did install SamsungKies and the device is detected. In Device Manager and in Eclipse device list too. I'm able to run my app! You are a saviour. :) Sad that I cannot upvote your answer. But I will as soon as I earn enough reputation :)

Comment: You can accept the answer, so that the question would be marked as solved (plus I get more rep! ;) )

Answer (score -1):

Download [PdaNet](http://junefabrics.com/android/) for Android. It was all I needed to connect my Samsung Galaxy Y with Windows 7.

Comment: Please consider re-wording your answer.  At the very least add a link to the program you are referring to.  If possible, quote the instructions here, so that in case the other site goes offline the information in your answer will stay relevant.

Comment: What does a tethering app have to do with configuring ADB?

Comment: And for the love of all things good please use standard English and find your shift key.