# USB Debugging for the Samsung Galaxy Y?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-y

I have connected Samsung Galaxy Y phone with Android Development Tool (ADT Eclipse) It doesn't recognize my device. I'm using window XP (64 bit) operating system.

I have also made the USB Debugging mode enabled, by Going to `Settings->Applications->Development`. But no reaction, I have referred this [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24105/how-do-i-configure-adb-for-the-samsung-galaxy-y) too no use.

I have also checked the Security -> Unknown Sources.

Simply, I want to use my mobile like emulator by connecting with IDE. But Its not working. If don't know its possible or not.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I have specified that in my question itself. I want to use my mobile like emulator by connecting with IDE and run my apps from IDE in my mobile.

Comment: what does `adb devices` output?

Comment: @Astor It doesn't showing my device in the available device list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848567/adb-samsung-galaxy

Comment: As you're working on Windows: Have you installed the device-specific drivers? Device "not recognized" suggests there might be something missing in that area.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure your phone is recognized by Windows?
You can verify this by looking in the Windows Device Manager if there is no error message or a yellow question mark on your device (you can find it by searching device manager in the search field of start menu)
If the driver is not installed you can found it on http://www.samsung.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check

> Security > Unknown Sources

Make sure that it is checked to allow installation from unknown sources

Comment: Yes. I have already checked it. Thq for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Many time there are softwares like [Easytether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mstream.easytether_beta), etc which don't allow adb to access your device. Make sure you don't have any such software installed which interfaces with your phone via usb.

If as stated above is not the case with you, you should try reinstalling [KIES](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) and the samsung usb drivers. That should certainly do the task for you.